# How to insert existing data from MongoDb to ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb

I started to migrate data from MongoDb to ElasticSearch. I am using 'monstache' for that. This connector is tailing the oplogs of MongoDb. 
The issue is that I already have data in MongoDb that I also want to send into ElasticSearch. What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I understand this may be a vague answer, but i think you could just write a small javascript app that establishes a connection to both DBs, then you flatten the JSONs from mongo that you wish to migrate, and then use the ES api to push them in bulk to your ES db.

'monstache' may have a better alternative. Their github page suggest they do.

https://github.com/rwynn/monstache

Hope this is of some help.